# cannot import my util module

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, joblib

I'm using `sklearn.externals.joblib` to persist a classifier model to the disk which in reality uses `pickle` module at lower level.

I create a custom `CountVectorizer` class named `StemmedCountVectorizer` and saved it in `util.py`, then used it in the script for persisting the model

```
import util

from sklearn.externals import joblib

vect = util.StemmedCountVectorizer(stop_words='english', ngram_range=(1,1))

bow = vect.fit_transform(sentences)

joblib.dump(vect, 'vect.pkl')
```

This my project structure using Flask:

```
   |- sentiment/
     |- run.py
     |- my_app/
       |- analytic/
         |- views.py
         |- util. py
         |- vect.pkl
```

I run the app with `python run.py` and try to load the persisted object with `joblib.load` in `views.py` but it does not work, I imported the `util` module but I receive the error:

```
ImportError: No module named util
```

can anybody give a solution to this? thanks

Comment: So this question doesn't really have anything to do with the `pickle` module not being found as your title would suggest. What does you project struture look like?

Comment: i have edited my title, so right now im using flask with usual blueprint project structure, the util.py script in the same dir as my views.py where i run the joblib.load() function

Comment: What does your directory structure look like

Comment: sorry i have edited my question once again, if i run the code in stand alone script it success, but if i run from flask (using the built in server) it failed,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a package/pythonpath problem. The system need to know where to locale your modules. Do you have `__init.py__` in `my_app` and `analytic` folder? The `__init__.py` file mark directories on disk as Python package directories. And the structure should be like this

```
   |- sentiment/
     |- run.py
     |- my_app/
       |- __init__.py
       |- analytic/
         |- __init__.py
         |- views.py
         |- util. py
         |- vect.pkl
```

then in your `run.py`, try import with

```
import my_app.analytic.utils
```

or

```
from my_app.analytic.utils import <yourClassName>
```

for details of python package, check [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).
And be aware of namespace problem.

Comment: thx for answering, yes i have the __init__.py file one inside my_app dir and one inside analytic dir, i do exactly as you said but it still not working, i keep getting the same error, if you want to see the traceback here https://gist.github.com/6379595981f130c40b68

Comment: do you have "E:\PROGRAMMING\python\projects\sentiment\" (your project path) in your **PYTHONPATH**?

Comment: Since the traceback shows that it's the `pickle` can't find your module, I suggest you try that.

Comment: im sorry for being late, but you were right, i added the specified path to the PYTHONPATH it worked perfectly, thx for yourr answer

Comment: What should go in the `__init__.py` file?